# How to install the QT module in my home directory?

Tags: perl, qt

I need to install QT in my home directory. How can I install QT? I have tried to install and use that module with one example. While running that program it showed me that can't locate Qt.pm in @INC. Can anyone give me solution to solve this problem. I need proper url to download the QT and tutorial for QT.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your home directory to `@INC`.  Some good examples of different ways to do that [here](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/588_Changing-INC-where-Perl-loads-its-modules.html).

Answer (score 1):

[local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib) is the correct way to install modules in a non-standard location.  There are excellent instructions in the CPAN documentation.